# TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, controller, ui-grid

I am having trouble trying to bind my data to the data gridOptions.  I read that doing a refresh would help load the data however when I add the logic it errors out.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <br />
    <b>{{msg}}</b>
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pagination></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.pagination']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
        rowHeight: 35,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        columnDefs: [
                { name: 'client' },
                { name: 'qa_ver' },
                { name: 'qa_build_no' },
                { name: 'qa_build_date' },
                { name: 'prod_ver' },
                { name: 'prod_build_no' },
                { name: 'prod_build_date' },
                { name: 'prod_deploy_date' },
                { name: 'deploy_src' }      
    ],
        data: 'jsonData',
        paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        paginationPageSize: 5,
    }

    $timeout(function() {
        getJSONData();
        $scope.data = jsonData;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data;
    }, 3000);
    
$scope.gridOptions = {
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ $scope.gridApi = gridApi;}
    }
    $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

Error thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'core' of undefined

    at new <anonymous> (dashboard.html:114)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4625)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10027)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8965)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8333)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8336)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8336)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8213)
    at angular.js:1715
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
```

Comment: Looks like you have `$scope.gridOptions = ` twice which would overwrite the config object. Also is it ok for data to start out as a string? `data: 'jsonData'` Maybe simplifying your example or trying it with static data would be helpful. The `$timeout` and `getJSONData()` (is that a request to an API?) make this example more complex and can be added back when you get it working with static data. I think you need to inject `GridApi` to call `GridApi.core.refresh()`. It's not available on scope.

Comment: @ScottyWaggoner Gratitude because I now have it working from your feedback and recommendations on a proper solution to my example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct form should be :

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
        rowHeight: 35,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        columnDefs: [
                { name: 'client' },
                { name: 'qa_ver' },
                { name: 'qa_build_no' },
                { name: 'qa_build_date' },
                { name: 'prod_ver' },
                { name: 'prod_build_no' },
                { name: 'prod_build_date' },
                { name: 'prod_deploy_date' },
                { name: 'deploy_src' }      
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ 
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
        data: 'jsonData',
        paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        paginationPageSize: 5,
    }

    $timeout(function() {
        getJSONData();
        $scope.data = jsonData;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data;
    }, 3000);


     $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();


..
..
.

}
```